# Powershell commands in pl / sql

Tags: oracle, powershell, plsql, command, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do I run powershell commands in pl / sql procedure? 
I am changing the active directory passwords in powershell.
How do I run powershell commands in oracle?

Comment: maybe this could help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132457/executing-shell-bash-from-pl-sql

Comment: credential_name ?

Comment: Please edit the question and explain with more details what you are [trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Changing AD passwords from database procedure sounds like a strange approach.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, PL/SQL can't directly run operating system executables.

Workaround is to create a database **job** using `DBMS_SCHEDULER` built-in package; in its `CREATE_PROGRAM` procedure, you'd use

```
program_type => 'EXECUTABLE'
```

Then create schedule and - finally - job. As it seems to be a one-time operation, you wouldn't actually *schedule* it to repeat in some intervals (e.g. every day, every week, every two hours, ...) but only once.

Comment: this is a common area for value in stored java procedures - to go out and do things on the OS...also falls in to the COULD vs SHOULD bucket